# Prove this is a homomorphism: $S_3 → S_4$ given by $σ \to (1 4)σ(1 4)$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Prove this is a homomorphism: $S_3 → S_4$ given by $σ\to (14)σ(1 4)$

Should I just plug in examples?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to prove a cooler and more general result: let $\;G,\,K\;$ be two groups such that there is an embedding $\;G\hookrightarrow K\;$ (i.e., a monomorphism from $\;G\;$ to $\;K\;$). Thus, we can consider $\;G\;$ a *subgroup* of $\;K\;$...

Then, for any $\;g\in G\;$ , the map

$$\phi_g:G\to K\;,\;\;\phi_g(k):=k^g:=g^{-1}kg$$

is a homomorphism from $\;G\;$ to $\;K\;$ .

With the above result, your question becomes almost boringly easy to solve.

Comment: Thanks! But can we say S3 is a subgroup of S4?

Comment: @davidD *Formally* no, of course...but we can **easily** embed $\;S_3\;$ into $\;S_4\;$ , can't we? That's in fact all we need. And we can embed it in lots of ways, but *the natural* one sees to work just fine. Can you see what "natural" way this is?

Answer (score 1):

Call the map $h$.  Then if $\sigma_1$ and $\sigma_2$ are arbitrary elements of $S_3$, we have $h(\sigma _1\cdot \sigma_2)=(14)\sigma _1\cdot \sigma _2(14)=(14)\sigma_1(14)\cdot (14)\sigma_2(14)=h(\sigma_1)\cdot h(\sigma_2)$.